# Why does my dropdown menu turn blue when I hover on dropdown items?

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

My bootstrap is making my dropdown color turn blue when I hover over a dropdown item. I put the code below, and I can't figure out how to change it. I think it is bootstrap. I was able to remove the dropdown items turning blue, but I can't change the title of the dropdown.

Current output:
[image: output]

```css
.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}

.top-navbar {
  background-color: #333;
  height: 40px;
}

.top-navbar-container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.top-menu {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.top-menu li {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.top-menu li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.top-menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.top-menu li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.top-menu .dropdown-item {
  color: #333;
  /* Grey text color for the dropdown items */
}

.top-menu .dropdown-item:hover {
  color: #333;
  /* Grey text color for the dropdown items */
}

.main-navbar {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 80px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.main-navbar-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.logo-container {
  width: 80px;
}

.logo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.menu-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu li {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.menu li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.icons {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.cart-icon {
  margin-right: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.logo-container {
  width: 78px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.dropdown-item:hover,
.dropdown-item:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
  /* Set the background color to transparent */
  color: inherit;
  /* Inherit the text color from the parent element */
}

.top-menu li .dropdown-item a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header">
    <nav class="top-navbar" data-bs-theme="dark">
      <div class="top-navbar-container">
        <ul class="top-menu">
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            Name
                        </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="register.php">Register</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="login.php">Login</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="icons">
              <a href="cart.html"><i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping fa-xl"
                                    style="color: #0000ff;"></i></a>
            </div>
          </li>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <nav class="main-navbar">
      <div class="main-navbar-container">
        <div class="logo-container">
          <img src="Noah Grocery Logo.png" alt="Grocery Store Logo" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="menu-container">
          <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="shop.html">Shop</a></li>
            <li><a href="support/support.html">Support</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Bootstrap is not on the code snippet FYI. I have tried online suggestions, but none of them worked.

Comment: Please make sure the code snippet reproduces the issue. Without seeing the issue ourselves the question is significantly harder to answer accurately.

Comment: For some reason the dropdown menu is not working on the code snippet.

Comment: Could it be fixed somehow using css?

Comment: Almost certainly, but like I said, without a [mre] people are unlikely to put the effort into an answer. I would start by removing the PHP and any HTML it would have hidden from the example, as well as adding example values for the PHP variables. That would clean things up a bit, and possibly resolve the example not functioning.

Comment: For some reason, the javascript is not working. I added it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like

```
.nav-link:hover {
    color: #fff;
}
```

in this case you trigger the nav-link directly.

here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/kushtra24/pen/zYMpvRK) of this.

Comment: it did not work

Comment: are you maybe loading your css code before the boostrap stylesheet so your code is being overwritten?

Comment: my bootstrap is in a different file that has the navbar file imported using php.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had to put the style in the actual html code for it to work. Thanks for your help!